# Adding Microsoft Accounts to Azure Active Directory

Tags: .net, rest, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Does anyone know a way in which to add Microsoft Accounts to Azure Active Directory programmatically?

Unable to find any Cmdlets in the AzureAD PowerShell module other than Work Account creation. Seems that the Graph API is the same as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not able to add the external users programmatically at present. If you want this feature, you may vote the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10372266-ability-to-add-microsoft-accounts-through-powershe) about using PowerShell to add external users.

And if you want to use other languages or the Azure AD Graph REST, you can also submit the feedback from link below:

https://feedback.azure.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you trye Azure Active Directory Authentication Library?
Here is the nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/